How to emulate completionHandler style code that can either return immediately and/or asynchronously with async/await?
I'm trying to understand how to use async/await with new Swift concurrency better. I learned how to write iOS apps using Objective-C a long time ago and still coming at stuff with that frame of reference.
Using traditional completion handler style logic, you could write an image fetcher function where you could check a cache, and if the image exists immediately execute the completion handler to return to the image. If the image didn't exist, you could call off to some background thread to do whatever work is necessary to fetch it (disk, network, etc) and then return the completion handler on the main thread later on. This is useful in cases where you want to use the UIImage immediately and not in the next run loop to avoid an image load being delayed or cause flickering (e.g. when setting an image in a UICollectionViewCell)
func fetchImage(url: URL, completion: ((UIImage) -> Void)) {
    if let image = self.images[url] {
        completion(image)
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        // Code to do the network fetch or whatever
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(...)
        }
    }
}

// On the main thread somewhere else
fetchImage(url: url) { image in
    cell.imageView.image = image
}

I'm not sure how to do this same behavior using async/await without having to do a non-async call separately to check the cache.
func fetchImageSync(url: Url) -> UIImage? {
    return self.images[url]
}

func fetchImageAsync(url: Url) async -> UIImage {
    if let image = self.images[url] {
        return image
    }

    // Do some async stuff to get the image
    self.images[url] = image
    return image
}

// On the main thread
if let image = fetchImageSync(url: url) {
    cell.imageView.image = image
} else {
    Task {
        if image = await fetchImageAsync(url: url) {
            await MainActor.run {
                  cell.imageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}

The negative of the above approach is there's no way to execute sync code on main thread in the happy path where the image already has been stored in the cache.

Why do you say "there's no way to execute sync code on main thread in the happy path"? Aren't you already doing that in the if branch of your second code snippet?

Also, you don't need MainActor.run if the if statement is already isolated to the main actor. Task inherits the actor context, unlike Task.detached.

a note: when calling completion handlers, best practice has been to ensure that the closure will be called always on the same thread. In your function fetchImage(url:completion:) you either call the closure from the main thread or from the calling thread. For the caller, this is a very unfortunate situation and can lead to subtle bugs. This reflects the current mind set: the unawareness of the underlying potential issues and the implicit assumption, that everything will be called from the main thread. With Swift concurrency, this issue - and this "restriction" does not exist anymore.

@Sweeper When I say "on the happy path" I mean that you will need to introduce this sort of if/else logic everywhere you try to use this ImageDownloader as opposed to the "legacy" way of just having one simple call.

@CouchDeveloper Yeah that's a good point, I was simply trying to illustrate that the completion handler is always called on the main thread in the legacy code.

The completion handler is only called on the main thread if the method is called on the main thread. The problem with the completion handler version is that there is nothing stopping someone from calling it off of the main thread, which is an easy mistake to make if, for example, the URL is retrieved from a previous network request, then the developer calls this method from within the completion handler of that previous network request.

Swift concurrency lets us explicitly label functions and types that are designed to be called from a specific global actor, and the compiler will guarantee that they are always isolated to that actor. In most cases, this is sufficient to provide a smooth UI experience and reduce unnecessary actor-hopping. So we could re-write the function and the image cache as an actor-isolated class:
@MainActor
final class ImageDownloader {
    
    enum CacheEntry {
        case inProgress(Task<UIImage?, Never>)
        case complete(UIImage)
    }
    
    private var cache: [URL: CacheEntry] = [:]
    
    func fetchImage(from url: URL) async -> UIImage? {
        if let cached = cache[url] {
            switch cached {
            case .complete(let image):
                return image
            case .inProgress(let task):
                return await task.value
            }
        }
        
        let task = Task {
            await downloadImage(from: url)
        }
        
        cache[url] = .inProgress(task)
        let image = await task.value
        
        if let image {
            cache[url] = .complete(image)
        }
        
        return image
    }
    
    private nonisolated func downloadImage(from url: URL) async -> UIImage? {
        do {
            let response = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            return UIImage(data: response.0)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    
}

Note how the cache tracks the state of the download. In the callback based version in the question, it's possible that an additional download will be kicked off while the initial download is in progress. This technique is based on code from https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10133?time=536 (The cache example is on the page, but not in the video, but it's worth watching the video.)
Now in your view controller you can call this method from a top-level task when you configure the cell:
final class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    private let items = ListItem.sampleListItems()
    private let imageDownloader = ImageDownloader()
    
    ...
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let listItem = items[indexPath.item]
        let imageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell",
            for: indexPath
        ) as! ImageCell
        let title = listItem.title
        print("Cell dequeued for: \(title)")
        
        // UIViewControllers are always MainActor-isolated, which
        // means this Task is on the MainActor, so there's no need
        // to call `MainActor.run`.
        Task {
            let img = await imageDownloader.fetchImage(from: listItem.url)
            imageCell.configure(text: title, image: img)
            print("Cell configured for item: \(title)")
        }

        print("Returning cell for: \(title)")
        return imageCell
    }
    
}

This will only ever hop off and back onto the MainActor when the URLSession is called in downloadImage(from:).
It also solves a potential source of bugs in the callback-based version: the callback-based method will only work properly when called from the main queue, but there is nothing preventing us from calling it from some other queue. If it is called from another thread, the code could crash due to simultaneous access to the cache.
Although the Task in cellForRowAt is always executed on the MainActor, it may not be executed until after other tasks on the MainActor. It's possible that this is leading to some of the flickering you're seeing. If this is the case, we can add some wrapper code to our ImageDownloader:
extension ImageDownloader {
    private func cachedImaged(from url: URL) -> UIImage? {
        guard case let .complete(img) = cache[url] else {
            return nil
        }
        return img
    }
    
    func fetchImage(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
        if let image = cachedImaged(from: url) {
            completion(image)
        } else {
            //No need for explicit MainActor switching, since it's an isolated class.
            Task {
                let img = await fetchImage(from: url)
                completion(img)
            }
        }
    }
}

An in the view controller:
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let listItem = items[indexPath.item]
    let imageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell",
        for: indexPath
    ) as! ImageCell
    let title = listItem.title
    print("Cell dequeued for: \(title)")
    
    imageDownloader.fetchImage(from: listItem.url) { img in
        imageCell.configure(text: title, image: img)
        print("Cell configured for item: \(title)")
    }
    
    print("Returning cell for: \(title)")
    return imageCell
}

That ultimately looks similar to your original version, but by isolating the ImageDownloader and its cache to the MainActor, we've eliminated the possibility of improper use leading to race conditions.

My understanding was that when you invoke a Task via Task { ... }, it provides an opportunity to co-opt execution, therefore it may execute the code inside of the closure at some other time, even if we're in the same concurrency context. I tested this out by adding a print prior to the task (pre), inside the task closure (inside), and after (post) and it is printed in the order of "pre -> post -> inside"

That's true, but it isn't thread or actor hopping. If you set a breakpoint in Xcode in that task at cell.imageView.image = img, you'll see that it is always on the main thread. If you change Task to Task.detached, then you will see that it could be on a different thread. Furthermore, if you set a breakpoint within the fetchImage function, it will always be on the main thread, so the potential bug of attempting to access the cache from multiple threads has been eliminated.

In other words, I don't think this is any more likely to cause flickering than if the order of statements in your viewDidLoad method was different, where all of the statements in the Task are written after the other code in the method.

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your response. I agree it's on the main thread, but it's running at some unknown point after which will cause at least one frame (or several, I am unsure how to quantify this) where the image will not be loaded as the cell comes into view. I've verified that this happens in a human noticeable manner vs the legacy style code not reproducing the same experience. The ordering that I'd prefer to have is "pre -> inside -> post" to guarantee that the inside block is able to run synchronously.

Hmm... I'm surprised there is a noticeable difference vs changing the order of statements in the calling method. In other words, I would have expected ...; Task {...}; ... to behave basically the same as ...; ...; cell.imageView.image = img. But I suppose it also makes sense that a UI refresh could occur in between, which is what you seem to be seeing. I'll think about it some more. I do think it's worth emphasizing that the legacy code is a bit problematic in that there is nothing preventing it from being called from off of the main thread, which is the cause of common bugs.

I created a simple project to try it out. I was not able to reproduce the flickering, but I could imagine it happening with more complex cells in a more complex collection view, since as you mentioned, the task could be executed later. I would definitely double check that the flickering isn't caused by something else though. Here's my example. It has an async/await branch, a callback-based branch, and one that uses async/await but avoids the Task if possible: https://github.com/elopinto/ImageDownloadCaching . I'll update my answer when I have a chance.

I've updated the answer to include everything we discussed in these comments. Hopefully that covers it!

Oh I see, so we're still using the a completion block like in the old days but behind the scenes in the non-cached version we'll kick off the async task. Got it. Let me give this a shot.

Yup, that's the best I could come up with in this case. In general you don't mix completion handlers with async/await, but since everything here is isolated to the main actor, it's not too different than if the code in fetchImage(from:completion:) was copied right into cellForRowAt. However, if you turn on strict concurrency checking and remove the @MainActor isolation from ImageDownloader, a warning will be thrown because a non-Sendable closure is being passed to a Task.

In order to adopt the Swift concurrency programming style, it's best to consider everything being async.
Also, there is no notion of "threads" any more. The notion of "main actor" or @MainThread in Swift concurrency exists due to dependencies which are confined on the main thread. For example, UIKit wants to be called on the main thread. Modern Swift concurrency provides a means to deal with these "legacy" components.
With Swift Concurrency, most programming challenges become more simple:
Starting with your image fetcher function.
func fetchImage(url: URL) async throws { ... }

Note, the function is async and can potentially fail. This is all a caller needs to know. In particular, a caller does not bother with threads or completion handlers.
The fact that an async function is declared async doesn't mean it has to suspend. It is totally fine to just return immediately:
func fetchImage(url: URL) async throws { 
    if let image = Cache.getImage(with: url) {
        return image
    }

    // fetch image asynchronously from service
    ...
}

So, even when the function is declared async it can return synchronously.
Assuming you add the code for fetching the image asynchronously from the server, the above code is all you need.
Note: when you want to call the above fetchImage(url:) function from another function, this calling function must be itself async ("everything is async"):
func foo() throws async {
    ...
    let image = try await fetchImage(url: url)
    ...
}

In order to integrate this code into "legacy" UIKit, one way to accomplish this, is shown below:
A method of your UIViewController subclass which will be called when the image URL is changing or being initialised:
private func onChangeOfImageUrl(url: URL) {
    Task { @MainActor in 
        do {
            let image = try await fetchImage(url: url)
            self.update(image: image)
        } catch { 
            self.handleError(error)
        }
    }
}

Side note: onChangeOfImageUrl(url:) as is could be called from any thread, but very likely we are calling it from UIKit code - thus we could make the assumption that we are running on the main thread. If we make this assumption, best practice would be to actually make it explicit, for example assert(Thread.isMainThread).
Another important concept:
When you look closely, the URL value will be passed through different "async contexts". It starts to exist in the main thread and gets passed to the function fetchImage(url:), which actually executes on a different async context. This requires the URL value to be "sendable", which basically means, that the value cannot be mutated while it is used in the other async context and thus, no data races can occur.
The function update(image:) is a method running on the main thread handling the update of the view.

Thanks for the lengthy explanation, but I have some assumptions, which may be wrong, due to my limited understanding of this new concurrency paradigm.
My understanding is that when you call async code from non-async context, it provides the opportunity to suspend.  I believe in your above example,  when doing Task { @MainActor in ... }, this MAY cause the execution inside of task closure to be executed at some later time. What I'd like to do is ensure that it is executable immediate 100% of the time if the image is cached like in the legacy example.

@NoNo This is not possible. Note: 1. calling an async function can only be done from within an async context, for example from another async function or from a Task's closure. 2. when calling an async function, the calling async function will be suspended until the called async function returns. 3. declaring a task with a closure in a synchronous context always performs a "sort of" dispatch to the Task's execution context, similar to Dispatch's someQueue.async { ... }. I would like to encourage you to thoroughly examine the available documentation. :)
